# react native vector icons not working after export on expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

I use

> react-native-vector-icons

and when I run app on emulator everything is ok 
but after the export with

```
expo build:android -t apk
```

and install on real phone all icons got hidden and not showing

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this you have to publish with "Managed" workflow instead of "Bare":

```
expo publish --target managed
```

Answer (score 0):

this you try?
*react-native link react-native-vector-icons*